# Looking for a way to scrape HTML with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a hopefully straightforward way of scraping all of the HTML from a webpage. Storing it in a string perhaps, and then navigating through that string to pull out the desired element.

Specifically, I want to scrape my twitter page and display my profile picture inside a new div. I know there are several tools for doing just this, but I would anyone have some code examples or suggestions for how I might do this myself?

Thanks a lot

UPDATE

After a very helpful response from T.J. Crowder I did some more searching online and found this [resource](http://blog.dtrejo.com/post/43757473805/scraping-made-easy-with-jquery-and-selectorga).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, this is easy. You just do an ajax call to get the text of the page, then use jQuery to turn that into a disconnected DOM, and then use all the usual jQuery tools to find and extract what you need.

```
$.ajax({
    url:     "http://example.com/some/path",
    success: function(html) {
        var tree = $(html);
        var imgsrc = tree.find("img.some-class").attr("src");
        if (imgsrc) {
            // ...add the image to your page
        }
    }
});
```

***But*** (and it's a big one) it's not likely to work, because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which prevents cross-origin ajax calls. Certain individual sites may have an open [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) policy, but most won't, and of course supporting CORS on IE8 and IE9 [requires an extra jQuery plug-in](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283).

So to do this with sites that don't allow your origin via CORS, there must be a server involved. It can be your server and you can grab the text of the page you want using server-side code and then send it to *your* page via ajax (or just build the bits you want into your page when you first render it). All of the usual server-side stacks (PHP, Node, ASP.Net, JVM, ...) have the ability to grab web pages. Or, in some cases, you may be able to use [YQL as a cross-domain proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax), using their server rather than your own.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! Really appreciate it! And for the code snippet. I suppose my next step is Node.js.

Comment: But If I'm signed into a server, I am not violating the cross origin policy according to this wiki page?

Comment: @the_prole: "Origin" is a combination of protocol, port, and host. So you could be using the same host and still be doing a cross-origin call.

Comment: But does this mean that I am signed in to another server? `http://username:password@www.example.com`/dir2/other.html