# How to load only a part of HTML page inside an object tag instead of the whole HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Html page, in which there is an object tag which loads another Html page. Thing is, I don't want to load complete Html inside this object tag. There is `div id="xyz"` in the second Html page and I would like to have it loaded just that.

How can we do that?

Please note, iframe can't be used. Java script may be used in the case of HTML alone can't do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You might just want to use a JS function and scrape it off your second HTML page i suppose?

Comment: How to do that? I have basic knowledge of Html/CSS but absolutely zero knowledge of JS. Could you show an example.

Comment: I'll be back with a jQuery example in a minute :)

Comment: BTW, I don't have any control over second Html page. It's a third party page.

Comment: Posted an answer, also [scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) is quite unreliable, if the other page changes their Markup it might not work anymore. If they do not have an API there sadly is no other solution to this tho.

Comment: Other page's markup doesn't changes, I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET", 
    url: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478837/how-to-load-only-a-part-of-html-page-inside-an-object-tag-instead-of-the-whole-h"
})
.done(function(data){
    alert($("#comment-58651828 .comment-copy", data).text());
});
```

This code loads my first comment from this exact page. The AJAX uses the GET method to access to the given URL and when it's done uses a css selector (`"#comment-58651828 .comment-copy"`) to find my comment and then alerts the text of it.

If you want to add that somewhere in your HTML just use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

If you want to test this code just use your console, you can only access StackOverflow pages from Stackoverflow itself. I might change the example for easier use.

Comment: I understood the code and it's working from console but I really have no idea how to put it into my html code. Tried enclosing it in script tag but it didn't work.

Comment: Gosh sorry, i forgot to mention you need to include jQuery :)

Comment: After fighting for hours, I still can't get it working. I added `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the header. I encapsulated above code in `<script></script>` but it doesn't do anything. 
Could you please provide an example which is very plug and play. I really have no understanding of JS. I googled a lot but still I'm missing something.

Comment: Well the problem is [CORS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21038701/3880255). In JavaScript CORS can throw all your code over, check in your console if you get a CORS error whenever you execute that code. If so, your thrid page does not allow CORS requests, which sadly makes it impossible to do this in JS.